# Is it possible to add/remove core functionalities of dotCMS?

Tags: customization, dotcms

I've jumped into a project that uses dotCMS. The problem is that there is only one book about this cms (which is pretty incomplete as far as I concern) and..even their official documentation is incomplete as well.

as far as I now, dotCMS is opensource, but I can't find any .java files.

Anyone knows if I can add/remove core functionalities of dotCMS?

I'm trying to add a new field to categories.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.  The dotCMS plugin architecture can provide 90% of most functionality you would be looking to add and have the added benifit of not breaking your upgrade path.  If you want to modify the source (and the core), you also have access to the community code here:

See:

http://dotcms.com/community/svn-access.dot

for instructions on how to download the source files and see:

http://dotcms.com/docs/1.9/Installation#InstallingFromSVN

on how to get it running from source.